# Git Local Repository Mapping

Tags: git, github

I had a question and I'd like some help with it

I've got a cloud repository with the files of the project that I work with, problem is, that is damn huge, and everytime we try to clone it, always we get problems with it

So my question is, it's possible to copy to a pendrive or something the local repository of the project, and after putting it on another computer, map it, so git understand that's a git repository that reflects a cloud repository and not just a local one

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 cases.

**(1) The project maintains a git config file:**

If this is the case simple copy-paste is enough. Because the project knows all the configs internally.

**(2) The project doesn't maintain a git config file:**

If this is the case you have to do followings.

- Get a copy of the **master branch** (assuming master is the default branch) and paste locally.
- Open cmd. And add the remote branch (origin) manually by the following command. `git remote add origin <clone-link>`.
- Now get a pull from origin/master branch into local/master branch with the following command. '`git pull origin master`'. This will make sure your master branch is in sync with origin's master branch.

Comment: Thank you kindly! It help me a lot

Comment: @user3633580 happy to see. :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to set another remote to your git repository:

```
git remote <REMOTE> <BRANCH>
```

e.g.

```
git remote pendrive master
```

After setting your remote you can push and pull from it.

git push

e.g.

```
git push origin pendrive



git pull <REMOTE> <BRANCH>
```

e.g.

```
git pull origin master
```